# Bendy bones breaks with Absolute handles

Tags: rigging

I'm triying to make and stretch and squash torso, when I use Absolute value on start and end handles the mesh breaks, it makes suddenly rotations. Also happens if I rotate to the right side, like it snaps
I want to use Absolute because of the curvature.
[image]

[image]

Comment: If "Absolute valor" is a third-party addon you'll have to ask the developers of the addon as we can only help with Blender and its built-in addons.

Comment: It's not a third-party addon, I'm talking about the bendy bone handles

Comment: Ah ok. I'd never heard of the term 'valor' with regard to Blender before! You must have meant 'value'?

Comment: Yeah haha, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the bone orientation, it was rolled -180°, so if I've would rotated a little bit to the left, the bone would make a fully rotation.
If the problem persists you could use a copy rotation constraint on the end handle and only copying the Y axis